# why does building gnome-seahorse on Linux Mint fail

Tags: gnome, ninja, meson-build

I am running Mint 19.2

Seahorse is not my friend.  The default version does not understand elliptic curves.  The flaptpack version can not generate ssh keys because it can't find `ssh-keygen`.  So I decided to go get my own version of the latest stable build.  I did a `git clone` and started the `meson` build process of satisfying dependencies.

After the `meson build` step I ran `ninja -C build`.  Thar seemed to compile ok but linking failed with:

```
Compilation succeeded - 2 warning(s)
[150/150] Linking target src/seahorse.
FAILED: src/seahorse 
cc  -o src/seahorse 'src/25a6634@@seahorse@exe/meson-generated_.._.._data_seahorse-resources.c.o' 'src/25a6634@@seahorse@exe/meson-generated_.._seahorse-shell-search-provider-generated.c.o' 'src/25a6634@@seahorse@exe/meson-generated_application.c.o' 'src/25a6634@@seahorse@exe/meson-generated_import-dialog.c.o' 'src/25a6634@@seahorse@exe/meson-generated_key-manager.c.o' 'src/25a6634@@seahorse@exe/meson-generated_main.c.o' 'src/25a6634@@seahorse@exe/meson-generated_search-provider.c.o' 'src/25a6634@@seahorse@exe/meson-generated_sidebar.c.o' -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,--start-group libegg/liblibeggdatetime.a libegg/liblibtreemultidnd.a common/libcommon.a libseahorse/liblibseahorse.a gkr/libseahorse-gkr.a ssh/libseahorse-ssh.a pgp/libseahorse-pgp.a pkcs11/libseahorse-pkcs11.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so -Wl,--export-dynamic /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so -pthread /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo-gobject.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsecret-1.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcr-ui-3.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcr-base-3.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgck-1.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpwquality.so -lgpgme -lldap -llber /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsoup-2.4.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavahi-common.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavahi-client.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavahi-glib.so -Wl,--end-group '-Wl,-rpath,$ORIGIN/../libegg:$ORIGIN/../common:$ORIGIN/../libseahorse:$ORIGIN/../gkr:$ORIGIN/../ssh:$ORIGIN/../pgp:$ORIGIN/../pkcs11' -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/me/tmp/seahorse/build/libegg -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/me/tmp/seahorse/build/common -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/me/tmp/seahorse/build/libseahorse -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/me/tmp/seahorse/build/gkr -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/me/tmp/seahorse/build/ssh -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/me/tmp/seahorse/build/pgp -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/me/tmp/seahorse/build/pkcs11
pgp/libseahorse-pgp.a(seahorse-gpgme-key-op.c.o): In function `seahorse_gpgme_key_op_make_primary_async':
/home/me/tmp/seahorse/build/../pgp/seahorse-gpgme-key-op.c:1939: undefined reference to `G_SOURCE_FUNC'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I'm sure that it is missing a library in the path somewhere.  I tried submitting an Issue in the git repo but couldn't log in to do so.

Answer (score 1):

`G_SOURCE_FUNC` was added in GLib 2.58, so there's a chance your local GLib version is not new enough.

Comment: Just FYI, I added the glib version check to seahorse's meson.build to prevent such things, so thank you for pointing out this non-ideal situation :-)